# how to repeated copy and paste in VBA

Tags: vba

What I need to achieve is as the second column below. I am a noob to VBA so any help will be much appreciated.

```
abc1200                        abc1200
MACHINE                        
supplier
cost
address
invoice number

abc2400                        abc2400
MACHINE
supplier
cost
address
invoice number
.
.
.
```

The code from recording are as below. Just need to repeat in select range

```
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
 Selection.Copy
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 ActiveCell.Offset(6, -1).Range("A1").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 ActiveCell.Offset(6, -1).Range("A1").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Selection.Copy
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste is only needed/used during macro recording. In VBA, it is much easier to directly assign the values, like
`targetcell.value = sourcecell.value`, etc.

So your first four lines would simply be:
`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Value`

You could even reduce this to easier forms, specifying the cell names directly, depending on the cells you plan to use.

Comment: Thanks Agan. But I only need to copy the first cell of every 6 rows to the right column (i.e. B:B).